# FFMPEG produces the following error: "error opening filters"

Tags: ffmpeg

I try to convert a .hav video file do .mp4 with the command:

```
ffmpeg -i 07.hav 07.mp4
```

and I get this error:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[mp2 @ 04f3eba0] Header missing
    Last message repeated 5 times
[mpeg @ 04e53c60] decoding for stream 1 failed
[mpeg @ 04e53c60] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Audio: mp2, 0 channels, s16p): unspecified frame size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, mpeg, from '07.hav':
  Duration: 00:15:00.13, start: 86159.434333, bitrate: 224 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p, 352x288, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 0 channels, s16p
[abuffer @ 04e4ca80] Value inf for parameter 'time_base' out of range [0 - 2.14748e+009]
    Last message repeated 3 times
[abuffer @ 04e4ca80] Error setting option time_base to value 1/0.
[graph 1 input from stream 0:1 @ 056fbb60] Error applying options to the filter.
Error opening filters!
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, since this command seems fairly simple to me?

Comment: Try with `ffmpeg -analyzeduration 20M -probesize 20M -i 07.hav 07.mp4`